# How can I insert blank lines within paragraphs

Tags: awk, sed

In this question, a paragraph is block of text divided by an empty line.
I am hoping for a solution in either sed and/or awk. I know that sed cannot handle muti-line operation, but I was wondering if there is any trick I could use.

So these paragraphs:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fermentum, libero eget interdum varius, arcu magna sagittis massa, a viverra mi mauris nec nulla. 
Nam porttitor massa euismod arcu egestas, at dictum enim imperdiet. 


Duis vestibulum, sapien at posuere tempor, mauris turpis varius nisl, quis consectetur felis leo eu mi. 
Nullam at sapien dictum, tristique dui quis, bibendum ipsum. 
Fusce semper rutrum sollicitudin. Proin lacinia molestie neque non aliquam. Maecenas commodo sodales nunc auctor dignissim. 

Ut lectus libero, elementum eu interdum et, efficitur eu odio. 
Nulla scelerisque nibh ut tortor finibus porta. 
Pellentesque maximus nunc in aliquet malesuada. Etiam ac auctor ex.


Sed ac egestas urna, a sagittis lacus.
```

would end up looking like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fermentum, libero eget interdum varius, arcu magna sagittis massa, a viverra mi mauris nec nulla.


Nam porttitor massa euismod arcu egestas, at dictum enim imperdiet.

Duis vestibulum, sapien at posuere tempor, mauris turpis varius nisl, quis consectetur felis leo eu mi.

Nullam at sapien dictum, tristique dui quis, bibendum ipsum.

Fusce semper rutrum sollicitudin. Proin lacinia molestie neque non aliquam. Maecenas commodo sodales nunc auctor dignissim.

Ut lectus libero, elementum eu interdum et, efficitur eu odio.

Nulla scelerisque nibh ut tortor finibus porta.

Pellentesque maximus nunc in aliquet malesuada. Etiam ac auctor ex.


Sed ac egestas urna, a sagittis lacus.
```

Comment: I do not understand your desired output.  Why are there 2 blank lines between Lorem and Nam (lines 1 and 4), only one blank between Nam and Duis (line 6), only one between Fusce and Ut, but again 2 before Sed?  Can you describe the spacing you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed.

```
sed 's/.\+/&\n/g' file
```

`.\+` matches one or more characters , so this would match only the lines which has atleast one character. `&` in the replacement refers to the matched characters.

Comment: use this `sed 's/.\+/&\n/g' file | sed '$d'` if you don't want to create a blank line at the last.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '#n
1h;1!H;${x
   s/\n/³/g
:cycle
   s/\([^³[:space:]]\{1,\}[[:space:]]*\)³\([[:space:]]*[^³[:space:]]\{1,\}\)/\1³³\2/g
   t cycle
   s/³/\
/gp
   }' YourFile
```

- need to load first the file in buffer to know surrounding (relative to new line) string
- sustitute new line with arbitrary cahr (to allow a restricition of this char, what posix sed does not allow with new line)
- add new line between 2 non empty (or only wioth space) string,
- if occur, cycle once again to allow even of peer string occurance to be also adapted
- reset the new line char
- print the result

Comment: What are those wierd `³`s ?

Comment: substitution char due to posix limitation on `\n` char in class

Comment: Cheers! Would you be able to point me to some documention for them as i've never seen them before ?

Comment: look at line `s/\n/³/g` and later  `s/³/` for the reverse. problem occur because `[\n]` is not allowed (as CR character class) in posix

Comment: Ahh right just worked out what you meant! Should have read you code more closely. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

For the (almost) exact output you asked for you could use

```
awk 'x{if(NF)print "";x=0}NF{x=1}1' file
```

---

#### Output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce fermentum, libero eget interdum varius, arcu magna sagittis massa, a viverra mi mauris nec nulla.

Nam porttitor massa euismod arcu egestas, at dictum enim imperdiet.


Duis vestibulum, sapien at posuere tempor, mauris turpis varius nisl, quis consectetur felis leo eu mi.

Nullam at sapien dictum, tristique dui quis, bibendum ipsum.

Fusce semper rutrum sollicitudin. Proin lacinia molestie neque non aliquam. Maecenas commodo sodales nunc auctor dignissim.

Ut lectus libero, elementum eu interdum et, efficitur eu odio.

Nulla scelerisque nibh ut tortor finibus porta.

Pellentesque maximus nunc in aliquet malesuada. Etiam ac auctor ex.


Sed ac egestas urna, a sagittis lacus.
```

---

#### Explanation

```
x{if(NF)print "";x=0}
```

If x is set, set it to zero. If the is more than zero fields(if `NF`(number of fields) is not 0) on the line then print a newline.

```
NF{x=1}
```

If there is a field on the line then set x to 1

```
1
```

Defaults to true and prints the line.

---

#### Resources

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

Comment: @EdMorton oh yeah, my bad :( I thought they wanted to keep the separations and just add a line between text lines. Maybe(hopefully) it was a typo, if not this answer can go in the bin :)

Comment: Certainly an error of text manual modification (because he has no working script) in posting because request state paragraph are separated by a empty line and this is not the case for this section

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you actually desire for output, but perhaps you are merely looking to have consistently double spaced output.  In that case:

```
 awk '/./{printf "%s\n\n", $0}'
```

Note that this will treat a line that contains only whitespace differently than a blank line (a line with no characters).  If that matters you could try:

```
awk '!/^ *$/{printf "%s\n\n", $0}'
```

or variations on that theme.

Comment: These don't preserve the space between paragraphs

Comment: @JID, no they don't.  Neither does the sample output!